# SQL not including duplicate values on a combination of 2 columns

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I am working on exercise 16 from sql-ex.ru. The problem asks the following:

```
Find the pairs of PC models having identical speeds and RAM. 
As a result, each resulting pair is shown only once, i.e. (i, j) but not (j, i). 
Result set: model with higher number, model with lower number, speed, and RAM.
```

The database schema is :

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT A.model, B.model, A.speed, A.ram
FROM PC A
JOIN PC B ON (A.model<>B.model)
WHERE A.speed=B.speed
AND A.ram=B.ram
```

But this displays duplicates of i,j as j,i. Here is my output:

```
model   model   speed   ram
1121    1233    750 128
1232    1233    500 64
1232    1260    500 32
1233    1121    750 128
1233    1232    500 64
1260    1232    500 32
```

As you can see, the values of i,j are flipped and counted as distinct values. Is there an easy way to get rid of duplicates like this? I am kind of lost on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "model with higher number, model with lower number" in the problem statement is a clue that you need to have a `A.model > B.model` condition somewhere. Join's `ON` condition sounds like a fine candidate:

```
SELECT A.model, B.model, A.speed, A.ram
FROM PC A
JOIN PC B ON (A.model > B.model) -- <<<=== Here
WHERE A.speed=B.speed
AND A.ram=B.ram
```

The `<>` is symmetrical; the `>` is not. Switching to `>` ensures that if `{i, j}` is in, then `{j, i}` will be out for sure.

Comment: That makes sense. Did not think about symmetrical values.