# Remove Duplicates based on two fields which can have reverse values in MySql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Say I had a table, Couples with Person1 and Person2 fields e.g.

```
Bob  | Alice
Ted  | Mary
Bob  | Alice
Jim  | Jane
```

Removing duplicates like `Bob | Alice` would be easy but say the data has been entered haphazardly and I had some couples in twice but reversed:

```
Bob  | Alice
Ted  | Mary
Jane | Jim
Jim  | Jane
```

How can I format a select/delete that would remove based on the two fields being identical in either order? I don't think a Unique Index would work here.

Comment: Looks similar to a sql question: [Not including duplicates on 2-column combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888960/sql-not-including-duplicate-values-on-a-combination-of-2-columns)  They're just talking about how to not display duplicates and if you really need to remove the lines then you can work from there.  You are providing a very simple example though.  Are you 100% sure that in every case where this occurs someone made a mistake and thus a record needs to be removed?

Comment: @MikeS I am 100% sure since I am the one who made "the mistake". It is a simple example of a more complex table I created by extracting from another table which had been on records with all 'Name1' records as Source resulting in Name1|Name2 and Name2|Name1 in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Couples table had an id column.
You could use this query to remove duplicates(considering that `'Bob','Alice'` is consider a duplicate of `'Alice','Bob'`)

```
DELETE FROM Couples
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM 
                   (SELECT MIN(id) as min_id
                    FROM Couples
                    GROUP BY LEAST(person1,person2),
                          GREATEST(person1,person2)
                   )T
                );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe81f/1
What the subquery does is it gets a minimum id for each grouping by LEAST(person1,person2),GREATEST(person1,person2)..which means `Bob,Alice` and `Alice,Bob` is considered the same group.
Then the outer delete statement delete rows that are not in the list of minimum ids (the duplicated rows)... The extra SELECT * is just to trick Mysql into deleting from the same Table in its subquery.

**UPDATE** For millions of rows using `IN` or `NOT IN` might be causing speed issue.  So try the below query it does the same but using joins instead of `NOT IN` and see if it's any faster

```
DELETE C1
FROM Couples C1
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(id) as min_id,
              LEAST(person1,person2) as per1,
              GREATEST(person1,person2) as per2
      FROM Couples
      GROUP BY per1,per2
      )C2
ON C1.id > C2.min_id
AND LEAST(C1.person1,C1.person2) = C2.per1
AND GREATEST(C1.person1,C1.person2) = C2.per2
;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f243e/1

Comment: Least and Greatest are brilliant solutions, I was trying all sorts of FieldA as FieldB permutations. Voted you up just for the idea, will test now and if works mark as the answer

Comment: The select works great, the Delete, even testing on a single A|B combination is taking forever. I did this as an update with a new field 'Dupe' which I can then just go delete. Not sure how to format the final here in comments...

Comment: The update version mentioned above took 5 minutes on a 26 million record table finding/flagging 2 million duples

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer (at bottom) with a query that doesn't use `NOT IN` but instead using JOIN...try that and see if it's any faster if you can rollback to previous version of data of 2million dups to see if it's faster using JOIN and let me know how that works out